# Validate files in a Folder with Control File

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am looking to validate the list of filenames present in a Control File with below mentioned structure and check if those files are present in the Folder using Azure Data Factory.

Control File Structure: SerialNo, FileName, RecordCount.

Folder Path: companysftp.xyz.io

So for example: If the control File contains,

1 data.csv 124

2 productdetails.csv 50

We need to check if the data.csv and productdetails.csv is present in the folder path mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards,
Arjun Rathinam

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory doesn't support Control File. Ref: [Supported data stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores).

In data Factory, only [Get Matadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) can help us list all the filename. To see: [Supported connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#supported-connectors).

1. `Get Matadata` all the file name from the source folder.
2. Using `if-condition` in Foreach to filter the filename `data.csv`
   and `productdetails.csv` is exist.

For example:

1.Get all the file name in the container backup:
[image]
[image]

2.Foreach `items` settings: send all the filename to Foreach:

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems
```

[image]

3  using `if-condition` expression to filter the filename:

```
@or(equals(item().name,'data.csv'),equals(item().name,'productdetails.csv'))
```

This expression is to filter if the name equsals `data.csv` or `productdetails.csv`,return `true/false`.

[image]

3.Then you can add the active in true condition and false condition.

Hope this helps.